# how add js files to create a responsive theme?

Tags: javascript, theming

is possible to add these files http://alvarotrigo.com/blog/fullpage-jquery-plugin-for-fullscreen-scrolling-websites/ in a theme? I created from scratch and from Zen without success. some how i think the jquery and javascript files are not active.

thanks

Comment: my info file

`code`stylesheets[all][] = css/examples.css
stylesheets[all][] = css/jquery.fullPage.css

scripts[] = js/jquery.fullPage.js`code`

Comment: Does the jquery.fullpage.css link work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the plugin on your subtheme's folder like "plugins/fullpage/".

Edit subtheme.info file adding:

stylesheets[all][] = plugins/fullpage/jquery.fullPage.css
scripts[] = plugins/fullpage/jquery.fullPage.min.js

Check if you need to add the other js files like vendor/jquery.easings.min.js, jquery.slimscroll.min.js...

It seems that the plugin needs jQuery 1.9.1 so https://drupal.org/project/jquery_update may be helpful

More info about the plugin: https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js